# Test SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

Does any website, lets us test SharePoint 2013 basic features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CloudShare](http://www.cloudshare.com) has the option of spinning up [SharePoint 2013 environments](http://go.cloudshare.com/SharePoint2013_Website-Banner.html) if you want to test on-premises

Office 365 has the [Sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp179924%28v=office.15%29) if you want to test the upcomming Office 365

Comment: Cloudshare is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the new SharePoint 2013 through Office 365 preview:

http://www.microsoft.com/office/preview/en/try-more-products

Answer (score 1):

[Training Videos](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123606.aspx) can help you getting the basic training in SP 2013. for testing it online better go with [Cloudshare](http://www.cloudshare.com/), but it is always good to test it locally as you will not able to test the complete features in cloudshare, like in local.