# Sharepoint Demo Sites to experiment Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, learning

When I open Sharepoint Designer 2010, I'm prompted to enter the site URL. The situtation is that I'm not really a Sharepoint Developer here and hence I don't have any access to sharepoint site(or have build any sharepoint site before). I wanted a demo site where I can learn sharepoint and its concepts.

Is there any demo site where one experiment upon to understand sharepoint better or at least see the controls and the basic code use in that site with the help of sharepoint?

Comment: Dont know about 2010 but 2013 can be tested. Link - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42418/test-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To learn more about SharePoint 2010 and to experiment with SharePoint Designer you can sign for [Office365 trial](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/free-office365-trial.aspx) and this includes SharePoint 2010 that can be used with SPD.

It is valid for 30 days. I doubt there is a free SharePoint 2010 hosting available anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Toni. I guess I have to setup a VHD of my own and try and experiment sharepoint there.

Comment: Yup, and there is a VHD ready for that too: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27417

Comment: Yeah! One of the biggest VHD ever! If I'm not wrong this VHD requires Windows Server 2008 R2. Isn't it?

Comment: It might work with Server 2008, but I am not sure.